# ignored declarative Security in IBM WebShere application server

Tags: spring, rest, security, model-view-controller, websphere

I have a spring MVC rest application that is deployed as a war file to IBM WebSphere application server v 8.5, i want to secure some of the rest api in this application, hence, i used the application web.xml and declare the security role i want, then i enabled the application security from the WAS console, but for some reason my security roles are ignored and i can access all  rest API that are supposed to be secured, any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>LBS_System</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/LBS/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Administrators</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>defaultWIMFileBasedRealm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Administrators</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MoictDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/MoICTAppUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>MoICTAppUnit</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-unit-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you restarted server after enabling `Application Security` in `Global security` settings? Also make sure your application role is mapped to some users/groups in the user registry.Also your url-pattern might be incorrect. Try to set it to `/*` for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will yes i restarted the server, and the role is mapped to a group, and the URL is correct, the /LBS/ is the context root of the application, i want any URL to my application with method other than get to be secured

Comment: Well, i tried your suggestion and put /* for the URL and it worked, but what if i want a certain URL? why is it wrong to include the context root of the application

Comment: You should be able to provide the url-pattern. If /* works then something isn't correct with the url-pattern provided. Is it possible you need to set the url-pattern in lowercase (eg. /lbs/* )? Can you post a sample POST string?

Comment: Well, i am sure about the URL but dont know why it dose not work, here is a sample URL for a post request: http://portal.egov.gov.jo:10039/LBS/locations

Comment: Also, to troubleshoot problems with security you could use this trace string 
*=info:com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webservices.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.xml.soapsec.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webservices.trace.*=all:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.AgnosticService=all:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.utils.SecurityContextMigrator=all

from https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not include your context-root  (LBS in your case) in the url-pattern. It is relative to your application context-root. The `/*` pattern protects all urls, but **only in your application**, not others. So if you just want to protect for example rest api, it is usually mapped to some sub path e.g. `/LBS/rest/something`, in that case you would put `/rest/*` in the pattern.

You should not include context-root in any mappings and url patterns in the web.xml, especially that application might be deployed under different context-root and in that case it would be broken.